# How to get mount point information from an API on Mac?

Tags: macos, api, mount

When I issue the `mount` command, I get entries like the following:

```
//abc@host/b1 on /Volumes/b1 (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by abc)
//abc@host/b2 on /Volumes/b2 (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by abc)
```

These indicate that I have two samba shares mounted.

I'd rather not try to parse `mount` command outputs, but I do want to retrieve the mount points of of attached filesystems, especially from samba.

Is there a API on the Mac that allows me to do this, either in C, or shell, or Python, etc. ?

Comment: You didn't include Objective-C or Swift in your list of languages. Are those acceptable?

Comment: Yes, please! The higher level, the better, but at this point, I'm looking for any way to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

You get an array of URLs for the mounted volumes using:

```
NSArray* keys = @[ /* ... */ ];
NSArray* urls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:keys
                                                                                        options:NSVolumeEnumerationSkipHiddenVolumes];
```

I'll get to the `keys` array in a moment. Once you have those URLs, you can obtain information about them using the "resource value" APIs of `NSURL`. You get a single value using `-[NSURL getResourceValue:forKey:error:]`. You get several at a time using `-resourceValuesForKeys:error:`. You can optimize the fetching of whatever values you're interested in by specifying them in the `keys` array passed to the `NSFileManager` method, above.

A key that may be significant for working with network shares is `NSURLVolumeURLForRemountingKey`. Other keys are listed in the `NSURL` docs. Both the Command and Volume keys apply.